# Debug msft teams bot channel conversation

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a bot that collects information in a private chat from User A about User B and then sends it to User B. I am collecting the information via Dialog and then formatting a HeroCard to be sent. I was using the Bot Emulator to test the private chat code, but I'm unable to test creating a new conversation () in the emulator without getting a 500 InternalServerError. When I deploy the code and integrate the bot into an existing Teams channel I receive 400 Bad Request responses.

Is there a tool to use that can help me debug creating a new conversation locally?

Comment: `I'm unable to test creating a new conversation () in the emulator without getting a 500 InternalServerError.` Can you clarify more about the problem? How do you create a new conversation? You can share the relevant code so that we can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need the user’s (User-B) unique ID and tenant ID to start [1:1 proactive conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive#starting-personal-conversations). Typically, these are obtained from a team context, either by [fetching the team roster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-context#fetching-the-team-roster) or when a user [interacts with your bot in a channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-channel).

Please check the [sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive#using-net).

Comment: Adding tenantId worked for me in creating conversation